# MODIS 04_L2 projection transformation

Tags: modis, hdf, modis-reprojection-tool

Trying to extract MODIS Deep Blue Aerosols from a number of years.

I have managed to open the HDF files in QGIS and ArcMap; however, have failed to reproject out of the sinusoidal grid so that the UK matches up with reference imagery.

I have tried MRT, which gave me an error every time I loaded a 04_L2 file into as follows

> Error in Module: ReadHdrFile Opening Input Header File

I couldn't find an explanation except perhaps, that I needed to use MRTSwath instead.

When using MRTSwath, the file loads with no problems but only displays two bands: the Aerosol_Cldmask and the Cloud_Pixel_Distance. I imagine because these are the only two bands still in a swath rather than grid projection.

I have looked into doing the conversion through gdal, however, when getting the needed GCP's via a gdalinfo command on the subdirectory, the produced information fails to list anything to do with GCPs. I thought this might be due to the version of gdal I have, but I seem to have version 2.2.4 which is well past what I believe I need for GCPs to be produced.

Any alternatives for reprojecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer this if anyone else is having issues, NASA actually provide post-processing for MODIS imagery. You can subset, transform to a tif, and reproject to a number of different projections.